# Add layer to UIPageViewController's view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, calayer, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController`. Inside its `viewDidLoad()` event, I'm adding a layer like below:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = .clear

    self.dataSource = self
    self.delegate = self

    let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    layer.path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height * 0.7)).cgPath
    layer.fillColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
    view.layer.addSublayer(layer)

    // The pages (`viewControllers` and subviews (a button and a PageController) are added here...
}
```

The problem is this layer covers the content of the pages (`UIViewController`s that are added by `setViewControllers`). I want the layer to be under the current view (like a background), not on top of it. How can I do that? I tried replacing `view.layer.addSublayer(layer)` with:

```
view.layer.insertSublayer(layer, below: view.layer)
```

But, that didn't work.

Comment: @matt I think my question is very clear. I want to add the layer as a background to my `UIPageViewController`.

Comment: Thanks, @matt! The other question helped me find a solution, but I don't think this is an exact duplicate of that question.

Comment: It doesn’t need to be exact.